# google play gameservice not responding in android

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am trying gameservice example i.e buttonclicker ,
in which when I select opponent from friend list, then some time it displays wait screen ,& in logcat it shows "Room created waiting for it to get ready"
& some time it shows force close dialog.
& some time it displays the login screen ,

what to do in this situation the error is not consistent?

Comment: Please add some code so that we can help you.

Comment: yupiii now itz working, i dnt know why,but the same code work for me,i think there is delay on getting response from google server